# Date format type "datetime" within foreach

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to format my date but not anything I'm doing wrong sign?

**This code does not show error**. The "echo" is empty.

```
<?php foreach ($Data as $v1) { ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">Published by <?=$v1->username?> Date: <?php echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $v1->date); ?></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <?=$v1->text?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` is for converting a formatted date to a `DateTime` object. If you want to print a formatted date, use `$datetime->format()`.

Comment: Able to find a solution! I share the answer, so you see someone else serve you!

Answer (score -1):

Able to find a solution! I share the answer, so you see someone else serve you!

```
<?php foreach ($Data as $v1) { ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  Published by <?=$v1->username?> 
  Date: <?php 
  $date = date_create($v1->fecha); 
  echo date_format($date, 'd-m-Y H:i'); 
  ?>
</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <?=$v1->text?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```